# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type... How to solve this?

Tags: c#, linq

So I'm trying to list in a KendoUI MVC Grid to list Employees and respective data, trough an YearPlanViewModel.

This is the Model.

```
 public class YearPlanViewModel
    {
        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public  String EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public List<Business.CompensationDayRequest> CompensationDays { get; set; }
        public List<Business.EmployeeVacationDay> VacationDays { get; set; }
        public List<Business.Displacement> Displacementes { get; set; }
        public List<Business.CriticalTask> CriticalTasks { get; set; }
        public List<Tuple<Business.Absence,Business.TimePeriod>> Absences {get;set;}


    }
```

So, for the DataSource function of my grid , this is my query

```
List<YearPlanViewModel> a = wtmEntities.Employee.ToList().Select(employee => new YearPlanViewModel
        {
            ID = employee.IDEmployee,
            EmployeeName = employee.FirstName + " " + employee.LastName,
            CompensationDays = employee.CompensationDayRequests.Where(cr => cr.Employee.IDEmployee == employee.IDEmployee && cr.Date.Year == 2015).ToList(),
            VacationDays = employee.EmployeeVacationDays.Where(vc => vc.Employee.IDEmployee == employee.IDEmployee && vc.Day.Year == 2014).ToList()
            ,
            Displacementes = employee.Displacements.Where(d => d.Employee.IDEmployee == employee.IDEmployee && d.StartDate.Year == 2014).ToList(),

            Absences = employee.Absences.Join(wtmEntities.TimePeriods,
            abs => abs.Period,
             tps => tps.IDTimePeriod,
             (abs, tps) => new { abs, tps })
             .Where(x => x.abs.Employee.IDEmployee == employee.IDEmployee)
             .ToList()
             .Select(t => new Tuple<Business.Absence, Business.TimePeriod>(t.abs, t.tps)).ToList()
             ,

            CriticalTasks = wtmEntities.CriticalTasks.Where(ct => ct.IDPerson == employee.IDPerson).ToList()

        }).ToList();
```

However I get the error that the title says, basically because the Compensation Days, Displacements etc etc all have a reference to the Employee that's why there's a circular reference.

However, they told me that I should use Includes in my queries so that shouldn't happen, so I tried with the CompensationDays and used the Employee Class instead of the ViewModel.

```
 List<Business.Employee> a = wtmEntities.Employee.Include(e => e.CompensationDayRequests).ToList();
```

The circular reference problems still goes on, and I don't know how should I change my query so it doesn't happen again. Whoever helps, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Working => Refactor (get it working, then refactor)

Working: The main problem is trying to do too much in a single action. When you use LINQ, action is deferred until the request is run, so a compiler can't catch issues (not that it would in this case anyway).

One way to start tackling it is get the information for the parent query first (looks like Employee here). You can then extract the information needed for other queries, building down the hierarchy.

This will make more work in compiling the information into List, but it will avoid the circular reference.

Refactor: Once you get it working, then refactor to make it more understandable and concise. You may find, once you pull out the pieces that will recurse, you can build your List with a single query.

NOTE: I wish I had a "just do this" answer, but I don't have the time to rip through all of the code and see if there is a particular piece that would solve the recursion problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two approaches I've used for this, both focusing on the point of serialization rather than on the model structure itself.  (Since the model is fine in server-side code and it's just serializing which causes issues.)

First, let's simplify a more contrived example to illustrate.  Something like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Clearly this presents an infinite recursion for a serializer, since any given child has a reference back to its parent.  Depending on how the API is structured, outside an API boundary a child doesn't *need* a reference to its parent.  When one gets a parent, one gets the children.

If this is universally true (such as when the Parent is the aggregate root and a Child never exists without one, and is never requested independently of one), then you can decorate the model property to prevent serialization:

```
public class Child
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

In server-side code it never makes a difference, but when serializing at an API boundary it simply doesn't include that property.  Client-side code doesn't need it.

If it's *not* universally true, and only this *one* operation needs to ignore the child, then just before serializing you can transform the model into a custom view model.  It's a little more manual, and may result in a little more repeated structure, but it gets the job done in a pinch.  It might look something like this:

```
var someParent = SomeOperationToGetAParent();
return new ParentViewModel
{
    Children = someParent.Children.Select(c => new ChildViewModel())
};
```

In this contrived example there aren't any other properties to use, but in something more realistic there would be.  You might even refactor that construction into the view models themselves, adding factory methods which produce view model instances given model instances.  Something like:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ChildViewModel> Children { get; set; }
    // other properties

    public static ParentViewModel BuildViewModel(Parent parent)
    {
        return new ParentViewModel
        {
            Children = parent.Children.Select(c => ChildViewModel.BuildViewModel(c)),
            // other properties
        };
    }
}

public class ChildViewModel
{
    // other properties

    public static ChildViewModel BuildViewModel(Child child)
    {
        return new ChildViewModel
        {
            // other properties
        };
    }
}
```

It can get pretty involved.  The code itself is trivially simple, but for large complex model structures there can be a lot of it.  Which leads to the practical appeal of using `JsonIgnore` instead.

Navigation properties are great in server-side code (and often necessary in Entity Framework), but they don't make much sense to a serializer.

Comment: In the Child classes, I don't have the property that points out to the Parent, but I do have that property in the DB Model from Entity Framework. I will give a try to the second example... :)